# Stabelizing Quarks?

Tags: quarks, fusion

I have been recently looking into something called Quark Fusion. The whole thing is a theoretical concept of colliding heavier and lighter Quarks to produce energy.
There is one thing to it tho. It is impossible to let those Quarks live long enough for actual storage and collision. But im now questioning if there would be any way to stabelize those Quarks and make a form of fuel cell or so posible by that, so they dont decay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no, for a long list of reasons. But just to keep things relatively simple:

Quarks are stable when left to themselves inside a proton, which is by far the easiest and most convenient way to store any unused quarks you might have lying around for some future purpose. But the amount of work required to pull a single quark out of a proton is more than enough to promote a virtual quark out of the vacuum and thereby create a new hadron before you have any chance of ever grabbing that quark and whisking it away and sticking it into a magic quark refrigerator instead.